# How to navigate to different website php (xampp)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, xampp

Currently, when I attempt to navigate to a different website's URL in my PHP code, my project just sends me to:

```
http://localhost/mysite/www.desiredURL.com
```

How do I navigate outside of 'mysite'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're missing your protocol in your links. You probably have:

```
<a href="www.desiredURL.com">link</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="http://www.desiredURL.com">link</a>
```

Comment: Very quick and easy fix. Thanks John.